# segmentation fault in binary tree in C

Tags: c

I was trying to implement my code to create a binary tree in C language.The code doesn't give out any errors but during runtime it results in segmentation fault .Couldn't figure out the reason why. please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*root = NULL;

struct node* create(int val)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->value = val;
    ptr->left = NULL;
    ptr->right = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

void insert(int val)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root=create(val);
    }
    else if(val < (root)->value)
    {
        (root)->left = create(val);
    }
    else
    {
        (root)->right = create(val);
    }
}

void traverse(struct node** root)
{   
    if(*root==NULL)
        printf("TREE EMPTY");
        return 0;
    while((*root)!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",(*root)->value);
        traverse((*root)->left);
        traverse((*root)->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int val;
    char ch='y';
    while(ch=='y')
    {
        scanf("%d",&val);
        insert(val);
        printf("Want to insert more elements ?(y or n) =");
        scanf("%c",ch);
    }
    traverse(&root);
    free(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Did you use a debugger? Where did the segfault occur?

Comment: `while((*root)!=NULL)` : doesn't change condition. Also `traverse((*root)->left);` argument type is mismatch. `insert` function is wrong.

Comment: `scanf("%c",ch);` --> `scanf(" %c", &ch);`

Comment: `free(root);` doesn't free all nodes.

Comment: thanx for the help ,the segmentation problem is now solved . I made some corrections in insert function .

Comment: please post code that cleanly compiles. On my computer Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc, the compiler outputs 6 problems with the code.  Perhaps if you were to correct those problems the application would run correctly.  As an example: in function: `traverse()`, return statement with a value in a function that is declared a returning `void`  and passing argument 1 from incompatible pointer type  and in function: `main() call to `scanf()` passing argument 2 as type `int` but it is expecting a argument of type `char *`

Answer (score 1):

As described by @BLUEPIXY the segmentation fault is caused by parsing the value of the variable `ch` instead of the address of `ch`. In addition to this you code appears to have some logical errors.

1. Your implementation of `insert` only looks at the root node and adds the new value its left or right child, depending on the root value. The desired behaviour is for insert to search down through the tree structure until it reaches a leaf node, and insert the new value here.
2. As indicated by @BLUEPIXY the `while ((*root)!=NULL)` in the `traverse` function is equal to `while (true)`, as the root element is never updated. Here, again, the desired behaviour is for the `traverse` function to navigate the tree structure (usually from left to right) and recursively visit the children of the current node. The code below implements a simple way to achieve this by simply calling traverse on each child, without the while-loop.
3. Finally, as @BLUEPIXY also points out, your call to `free` with `root` as argument does not release the entire tree. `Free` only releases the memory block pointed to by its argument. It does not recursively follow pointers within that memory block. In order to release all resources held by the tree structure you need to traverse the tree again and call `free` on every node.

The following code, based on your code, implements binary tree. Note that the tree is not likely to remain balanced, as it grows. To achieve a balanced binary tree you need to remodel the tree when inserting a new node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

node *root = NULL;

node* create(int val)
{

    node *ptr;
    ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->value = val;
    ptr->left = NULL;
    ptr->right = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

void insert_(node *root, int val)
{
  if (val < root->value)
  {
    if (root->left != NULL)
    {
        insert_(root->left, val);
        } else {
        root->left = create(val);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (root->right != NULL)
        {
            insert_(root->right, val);
        } else {
            root->right = create(val);
        }
    }
}

void insert(int val)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = create(val);
    }
    else
    {
        insert_(root, val);
    }
}

void traverse(node *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        printf("E");
        return;
    }
    printf("%d (", root->value);
    traverse(root->left);
    printf( ") (");
    traverse(root->right);
    printf( ")");
}

void free_tree(node *root)
{
      if (root == NULL) {
            return;
      }
      free_tree(root->left);
      free_tree(root->right);
      free(root);
}

int main()
{
      int val;
      char ch='y';
      while(ch=='y')
      {
            scanf("%d",&val);
            insert(val);
            printf("Want to insert more elements ?(y or n) =");
            scanf(" %s", &ch);
      }
      traverse(root);
      free_tree(root);
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your traverse() function.

1. when you are checking the root is NULL or not then you have missed the braces that include the `printf()` statement and `return 0` statement;

if you dont do this then first it will check 
whether (root is NULL or not)
if yes -> then print the statement "TREE EMPTY" and return ;
if no -> it directly return from the function.

```
void traverse ( struct node **root )
{
    if ( *root == NULL )
    {
        printf ("TREE EMPTY");
        return 0;
    }
    while ((*root) != NULL )
    {
        printf ("%d", (*root) -> value);
        traverse ((*root) -> left);
        traverse ((*root) -> right);
    }
}
```